# Define a "nested" object constructor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, nested

Is it possible to define an object within another object? I'm thinking something like this:

```
function MyObj(name) {
    this.name = name;

    function EmbeddedObj(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And I could then create an EmbeddedObj like this:

```
var myEmbeddedObj = new MyObj.EmbeddedObj();
```

Meme for bonus points: Objectception! :o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, and no.

```
function MyObj(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
MyObj.EmbeddedObj = function EmbeddedObj(id) {
    this.id = id;
}
new MyObj.EmbeddedObj(42);
```

Would run, but it might not yield the expected results for "embedded object" (see comment).

Note that in the case of `new expr` the expression is evaluated *first* so, in this case it creates a new object using the function-object evaluated from `MyObject.EmbeddedObj` as a constructor. (There is a silly rule with parenthesis in the expression, but that's another story.)

---

Now, if a "parent" and "child" relationship was desired, that could be done, using a more round-about method:

```
function Parent (name) {
   this.name = name;
   var parent = this; // for closure
   this.Child = function Child () {
      this.Parent = parent;
   }
}

// create new parent object
var parent = new Parent();       
// each new parent has a different Child constructor and
// any function-object can be used as a constructor
var child = new parent.Child();
// true: child is "bound" to parent
child.Parent === parent;
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say 'might not yield the expected results'?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville They are two *unassociated* constructors. It is just a coincidence that `MyObject` names the first constructor and `MyObject.EmbeddedObj` names the second constructor (it might as well be `foobar`). That is, it is *not* like a *nested class* in Java (where the nested class is a "child" of the containing "parent" class).

Comment: @ElliotBonneville I've updated with an example of how to setup a parent/child relationship.

Answer (score 3):

```
function MyObj(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

MyObj.EmbeddedObj = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
}

var myEmbeddedObj = new MyObj.EmbeddedObj();
```

Does that look like what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

### Here is example of nested constructor.

```
function cimdb(name,review,year) {

 function nestedConstructor(name,review,year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.review = review;
    this.year = year
};

    this.name = name;
    this[name] = new nestedConstructor(name,review,year);

}



  var lionking = new cimdb("The Lion King", "The lion King review ..", 2015);
```

---

I  guess this is what you mean by nested object constructor.

Comment: So how do I created an instance of nestedConstructor from outside of the cimdb method?

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way to nest other objects in a constructor is to create its field and then create a new object when invoking the constructor.** Below is an example:

```
function Product(name, price, category, producer) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.category = category;
    // nested constructor
    this.producer = producer;
}

function Producer(contributor, address) {
    this.contributor = contributor;
    this.address = address;
}

let prod1 = new Product("Milk", 2.5, "Dairy", new Producer("Nestle", "Warszawa"));
```